# Intercept keystrokes to a window

Tags: winapi, keyboard, keyboard-hook

Is it possible to intercept a keystroke (and characters) sent to a window? By intercept, I mean play man-in-the-middle, instead of having just hooks onto the Window.

I'd like to filter (i.e. eliminate some keystrokes) keystrokes to a window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SetWindowsHookEx().  Just eliminating keystrokes can be done with a simple WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook.  It is not a global hook so is easy to get right.  Googles very well too.

Comment: You are right. It's not a hook easy to get right. Someone actually made a DLL for this http://bobmoore.mvps.org/Win32/w32tip69.htm